# If a set literal is of type set then what is its class in dart?

Tags: dart, types, set

So the following code snippet

```
Set mySet = {1,2,3};
```

is an instance of type Set which is permissible, however what would the class of the set literal be. I have tried to search for this, however I have found no answer in the dart documentation.

Comment: What do you mean?  The class is its type.  What is your distinction between "class" and "type"?

Comment: Set is an abstract class, which means it can't be instantiated. Therefore, the set literal must have a different class but what class is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal exists only in your source code.  Asking for its "class" doesn't make a lot of sense.

Using a `Set`, `Map`, or `List` literal is just syntactic sugar for invoking a corresponding constructor.  The [`Set` factory constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set/Set.html) constructs a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet-class.html).

However, you'll see that `LinkedHashSet` is also abstract. Its factory constructor returns an instance of a private, internal class.  You can see its typename via `print(Set().runtimeType)`; the actual type might be different for different platforms and is unlikely to be useful to you.